Calling model freezes and opens new windows in exe. ultralytics+tkinter+pyinstaller
I'm having an issue where a Tkinter app, when converted to exe, will freeze and open a new window every time a YOLO model is loaded. My original program is quite extensive, so I've recreated one demonstrating the issue:
from io import StringIO
memory_buffer = StringIO()
sys.stdout = memory_buffer
import tkinter as tk
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2 as cv
global testimg
testimg = cv.imread("testimg.jpg")

class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk() # root here is window name now
        self.root.geometry("600x400")
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.root.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.root.rowconfigure(2, weight = 1)
        self.buttonmodel1 = tk.Button(self.root, text = "Model 1", bg = "#c9c9c9", bd= 5, width = 200, command = self.button1pressed)
        self.buttonmodel1.grid(row =0, column=0, sticky= "WENS", padx = 3)
        self.buttonmodel2 = tk.Button(self.root, text = "Model 2", bg = "#c9c9c9", bd= 5, width = 200)
        self.buttonmodel2.grid(row =1, column=0, sticky= "WENS", padx = 3)
        self.buttonmodel3 = tk.Button(self.root, text = "Model 3", bg = "#c9c9c9", bd= 5, width = 200)
        self.buttonmodel3.grid(row =2, column=0, sticky= "WENS", padx = 3)
        self.root.mainloop() 
        
    def button1pressed(self):
        global testimg
        model1 = YOLO("model1.pt")
        model2 = YOLO("model2.pt")
        model3 = YOLO("model3.pt")
        resultsmodel1 = model1.predict(testimg)
        print("model1")
        resultsmodel2 = model2.predict(testimg)
        print("model2")
        resultsmodel3 = model3.predict(testimg)
        print("model3")
MyGUI()

converted to exe using:
pyinstaller --collect-data ultralytics Model_Test.py --onefile --windowed

with
from io import StringIO
memory_buffer = StringIO()
sys.stdout = memory_buffer

Used to mitigate the known issue with using ultralytics + pyinstaller:
https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/7064
Problem when converting Python with Ultralytics to EXE file
When debugging in VS 2022 there are no such issues, only once the program has been packed and run as an exe. All model files are in the same directory as the exe.
It appears that as soon as .predict() is called the main window freezes, the console pops up momentarily, and a new identical window appears. If closed the program will resume as intended with no additional errors:

Seems like a very niche issue, I would guess something is going wrong across Ultralytics + Pyinstaller + Tkinter.
Please do advise or let me know if more information is needed.

did you run .exe in console to see error messages?

maybe you should redirect stdout to some file - to see what is in stdout. OR maybe you should use print() to see which line of code is executed and what you have in variables.

exe is self extracting .zip file - it creates temporary folder and it extract your code to this folder - and it runs code from this folder. If it needs some file with data then you have to add it inside .exe (as resource) or you have to use /full/path/to/local/file

Furas, even if packed using --console there is no output due to sys.stdout being ammended. Print statements are already included in the program, but do not display. All files are included in the same directory as the .exe already.

it doesn't matter if other files are in the same folder as .exe because .exe extracts .py code in temporary folders and it runs .py in this temporary folder - so code may search other files in temporary folder - not in folder where is .exe. You may have to have to include other files inside .exe as resource.

maybe for test don't redirecte sdtout - and run code in console to see all outputs. You could also use logging to write information - it can be useful also later when you will use program because it allow to keep older information and check it later.

its look like you encountering an issue and its complex interactions between tkinter loop there's the solutions for that:

Threading: best way to predict freezing, it can prevent from that
Standard Output Handling: ensure that the stdout redirection does not interfere with the gui
PyInstaller config: make sure all dependencies included in exe file

Here's the code solution :
import tkinter as tk
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2 as cv
import threading
import sys
from io import StringIO

memory_buffer = StringIO() # Output Handling
sys.stdout = memory_buffer

global testimg
testimg = cv.imread("testimg.jpg")

class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("600x400")
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.buttonmodel1 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Model 1", bg="#c9c9c9", bd=5, width=200, command=self.button1pressed)
        self.buttonmodel1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="WENS", padx=3)
        self.buttonmodel2 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Model 2", bg="#c9c9c9", bd=5, width=200)
        self.buttonmodel2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="WENS", padx=3)
        self.buttonmodel3 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Model 3", bg="#c9c9c9", bd=5, width=200)
        self.buttonmodel3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="WENS", padx=3)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def button1pressed(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.run_models).start() # Threading solution

    def run_models(self):
        global testimg
        model1 = YOLO("model1.pt")
        model2 = YOLO("model2.pt")
        model3 = YOLO("model3.pt")
        resultsmodel1 = model1.predict(testimg)
        print("model1")
        resultsmodel2 = model2.predict(testimg)
        print("model2")
        resultsmodel3 = model3.predict(testimg)
        print("model3")

MyGUI()

PyInstaller Script 4 that is same as yours
If problem still exist do these:

Check Output : Check any errors for missing dependencies or smth like that
Run without --windowed : Look the console for debugging if issue continues
DEpendencies : Ensure the all YOLO dependencies in same directory as the exe files

If still dont works Click here
